# enabling RewriteEngine in apache (uniserver) causes 403 on all files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I'm trying to do is to enable a 'dry' version of url rewriting in Apache only to check if it is working and actually do not rewrite anything yet.

The simplest `.htaccess` that I came up with is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

But this still doesn't work. All files, all paths I'm trying to request, no matter if they exist or not return `403 Forbidden`

What I need is any example htaccess that has redirection inside that must work, that is allow access to all existing files and folders and do it's job only when the file requested doesn't exit.

Comment: How do you intend to test a rewriterule without any actual rule? rewriteconds alone won't do anything

Comment: @Capsule: But it does, it blocks all other requests. I want a dumy one to check nothing is broken in apache server itself.

Comment: Add `RewriteRule ^dummy http://google.com [R]`. Then go to domain.com/dummy. If you get redirected to google, then it works

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I've not added these lines:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

or

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```